# Illegal Break Statement on ajax call while looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop

I'm trying to make an ajax call inside a for loop and it throws the exception "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement". It happens on the last line when calling the function getProviderDetails().

I also tried making the call sync but it didn't work either. Even changed the loop for a regression as I read in other answers with no luck.

Here is the code:

```
    function getProviderDetails(origin,destination,outbound,inbound) {
        $.get("/api/provider.php", {
            async: false,
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            outbound: outbound,
            inbound: inbound
            },
        function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            var values = data.split(";");
            if (dates.length < 2) {
                break;
            }
            var price = values[0];
            if (price < 1) {
                break;
            }
            var link = values[1];
            printData(origin,destination,outbound,inbound,price,link);
        });
    }

    function printData(origin,destination,outbound,inbound,price,link) {
        var row = "<tr>"+"<td>"+origin+"</td>"+"<td>"+destination+"</td>"+"<td>"+outbound+"</td>"+"<td>"+inbound+"</td>"+"<td>"+price+"</td>"+"<td>"+link+"</td>"+"</tr>";
        $('#prices').append(row);
    }

    function getMonths(origin,destination) {
        $.get("/months.php", {
            async: false,
            from: origin,
            to: destination,
            country: "AR",
            currency: "ARS"
        },
        function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            var counter = 0;
            var months = [];
            for (var key in data) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > 2) {
                    break;
                }
                getDates(origin,destination,key);
            }
        });
    }

    function getDates(origin,destination,month) {
        $.get("/api.php", {
            from: origin,
            to: destination,
            month: month,
            country: "AR",
            currency: "ARS"
            },
        function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            var counter = 0;
            for (var key in data) {
                counter++;
                var outboundDates = [];
                var inboundDates = [];
                if (counter > 10) {
                    return;
                }
                var dates = key.split(".");
                if (dates.length < 2) {
                    return;
                }
                var outbound = dates[0];
                var inbound = dates[1];
                //outboundDates.push(outbound);
                //inboundDates.push(inbound);
                //iterateDates(origin,destination,outboundDates,inboundDates,0);
                getProviderDetails(origin,destination,outbound,inbound);                    
            }
        });
    }



    getMonths("BUE","MAD");
```

Comment: If you simply want to "break" out of the function, use `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: The `break` keyword is for control statements (with the exception of `if`), not functions. As Rich pointed out, `return` is how you "break" out of a function.

Comment: The exception is thrown on the last line when calling getProviderDetail so it never makes the break statement. It is something else.

Comment: Did you try running the updated code? Because you shouldn't be getting the error anymore. It was `break` that was breaking it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change the code to "fix" it, it invalidates the question.

Comment: *"The exception is thrown on the last line when calling getProviderDetail so it never makes the break statement"* right, because it's illegal where it is. it doesn't matter that that part of the code hasn't run yet. Paste this into your console: `function foo () { break; }` and you'll get the same result.

Comment: Returning from a callback also will not stop your for loop. Using for loops and async: false for this is awful, surely you can come up with some other way of solving this,

Comment: It has nothing to do with the break, I edited it because it's not the issue. If I try changing the getProviderDetail function content to just a console log, no exception is thrown. So it's something about the ajax call inside a loop. Async false is just something else I tried that didn't work, I know is wrong.